# Rails - Has Many multiple nested association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Let's say I have three models: A, B, C.

```
class A
  has_many :bs
end

class B
  has_many :cs
end
```

What is the easiest way to declare some association in A so I can access All C's it has through B? So I can call something like `a_object.c_objects`.
Dumb question, but I'm kinda stuck. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you already have established the associations

> A has many B, and B has_many C

then you are all set up. Only thing to do is adding the following code (no database changes needed):

```
class A
  has_many cs, through: :bs
end
```

and use `a_object.c_objects`.

Comment: @RonanLopes no probs :)

Answer (score 1):

```
class A
  has_many :cs, through: :bs
end
```

for this should [rails link](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association)

after this you will `use and use a_object.c_objects`

Comment: how is this answer bringing anything new compared to already given one? :)

Comment: this is having link for detail  has_many :cs, through relation

Comment: do you agree, that apart from the link the answer is a duplicate of the given one?

Comment: @Sunny, you may just want to include the link as a reference beneath Andrey's answer and delete yours. It looks very much like you copied and pasted his answer.